# Is there a formal name for $ sign in PHP

Tags: php

Is there a formal name for $ sign in PHP? I just call it the dollar sign but I have an interview upcoming soon and don't want to sound very immature with the language.

Comment: It is a variable identifier. If you get asked about it you should turn down the job. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php

Comment: Even the PHP docs refer to it as "the dollar sign": http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php

Comment: ....and run, run, as fast as one possibly can! @JayBlanchard

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Variables in PHP are represented by a **dollar sign** followed by the name
>   of the variable.

If they use it, use it, too.

Src: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php

Comment: @JayBlanchard - They being the people writing the official PHP docs I believe.

Comment: Ah! A little foggy headed today @j08691